# How to leverage wsdl API code with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, web-services, soap

I would like to use PowerShell to create new users in an external application via their webservice API.  Sample SOAP code from the API looks like this:

```
POST /pmomsws/oms.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: swfulfillment.1touchpoint.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Header>
        <AuthenticationHeader xmlns="http://omscom/">
            <Username>user123</Username>
            <Password>xxxxxxxx</Password>
        </AuthenticationHeader>
        <DebugHeader xmlns="http://omscom/">
            <Debug>true</Debug>
        </DebugHeader>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <AddPreRegisteredUser xmlns="http://omscom/">
            <user>
                <ORDOBY>
                    <CustomerID>bill.smith@smith.com</CustomerID>
                    <OrderEntryView>
                        <Description>General Users</Description>
                    </OrderEntryView>
                    <Mailer>
                        <Name>
                            <FirstName>Bill</FirstName>
                            <LastName>Smith</LastName>
                            <FullName>Bill Smith</FullName>
                        </Name>
                        <Address>
                            <Address1>112 Smith St</Address1>
                            <City>Dallas</City>
                            <State>Texas</State>
                            <PostalCode>77346</PostalCode>
                            <Country>US</Country>
                        </Address>
                        <BillingInfo>
                            <TaxExempt>false</TaxExempt>
                            <TaxExemptApproved>false</TaxExemptApproved>
                        </BillingInfo>
                    </Mailer>
                    <Client>false</Client>
                    <NoOfferQuantityDropDown>false</NoOfferQuantityDropDown>
                    <RequirePasswordNextLogin>false</RequirePasswordNextLogin>
                    <CategoryAccessGroup>
                        <Description>General User</Description>
                    </CategoryAccessGroup>
                    <MasterApproverStatus>false</MasterApproverStatus>
                    <IsInactive>false</IsInactive>
                </ORDOBY>
                <Graph1>0</Graph1>
                <Graph2>0</Graph2>
                <Graph3>0</Graph3>
                <Graph4>0</Graph4>
                <Graph1Type>None</Graph1Type>
                <Graph2Type>None</Graph2Type>
                <Graph3Type>None</Graph3Type>
                <Graph4Type>None</Graph4Type>
                </user></AddPreRegisteredUser>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have some PowerShell code started but not sure the way to create new objects.  Any help would be appreciated!  I am looking to create the new user by sending customer ID, Description, Name and Address info, etc

```
$username = "xxxxxxx"
$password = "yyyyyyy"
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

$webservice = New-WebServiceProxy -uri "https://swfulfillment.1touchpoint.com/pmomsws/oms.asmx?wsdl" -Namespace "omscom" -Class "AddPreRegisteredUser"-Credential $cred

#not sure how to format this part to create the users
$attributes = New-Object("omscom.Name")
$attributes.FirstName = "Bill"
$attributes.LastName = "Smith"
$attributes.FullName = "Bill Smith"
```

Alternatively if I can create XML for my input data should I feed xml to the powershell?

Comment: What did you search for? For example ['all you ever wanted to know about PowerShell objects'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27all%20you%20ever%20wanted%20to%20know%20about%20powershell%20objects%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27all%20you%20ever%20wanted%20to%20know%20about%20powershell%20objects%27&sc=0-54&sk=&cvid=DEE3048116384F29B1DD7F79FB19B052). ['send PowerShell object to API'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27send%20PowerShell%20object%20to%20API%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27send%20powershell%20object%20to%20api%27&sc=4-31&sk=&cvid=7B9D7C5A0E094CACB4C7817AE94583D8).

Comment: `New-WebServiceProxy` should generate method stubs for the service endpoint, if you write `$webservice.AddPreRegisteredUser` (without parentheses at the end) and hit enter in the prompt you should be able to see the method signature

Comment: I get this returned from $webservice.AddPreRegisteredUser        
 OverloadDefinitions                                                             
-------------------                                                             
omscom.AddPreRegUserResult AddPreRegisteredUser(omscom.UserPreRegistered user)

Comment: Take a look at the type name in the method parameter list - `$userInstance = New-Object omscom.UserPreRegistered` should do the trick

Comment: PS C:\Scripts\OneTouchPoint> $userinstance = New-Object omscon.UserPreRegistered
New-Object : Cannot find type [omscon.UserPreRegistered]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:17
+ $userinstance = New-Object omscon.UserPreRegistered
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: In the XML example above, how can I fill the values such as CustomerID, FirstName, LastName, etc from a list of data stored in a variable?  I have the user data stored in $members for example.  I want the data in the xml to update and loop through for each user in $members.  I have $members.firstname, $members.lastname etc available. The API only accepts a single user created at a time.